# Does a page opened by window.open share browser resources with the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, devtools

My main page takes up too much memory, so I want to open a new window to reduce the pressure on the
main page. But it takes up same memory with the parent page and even more.
How can I open a new page and it use different memory?[contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLn2V.png)

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A modern web browser may spawn a new process if you use another domain for the second page. But not necessarily, and you are not going to reduce the memory usage by doing that.